# How does windows differentiate between USB keyboard and USB joystick?

Tags: windows, usb, keyboard, game-controller

I am trying to make a hack that will allow a second keyboard to get detected as a joystick. I wanted to know how does windows know if a USB keyboard is connected or a USB joystick is connected. OR does it not know at all what is connected. It just sees what input is coming from the USB -- a joystick key or a keyboard key. However I suspect the latter to be untrue as if that was possible then Games would not be able to know whether joystick is connected or not.
*So to summarize I want to know how does windows know if a USB keyboard is connected or a USB joystick is connected..?*

Comment: Some reading: [USB device descriptors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff539283(v=vs.85).aspx), [Developing Windows client drivers for USB devices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/hardware/hh406260(v=vs.85).aspx), [USB device class drivers included in Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/hardware/ff538820(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @Techie007, you really should post that as an answer. Maybe flesh it out a bit.

Comment: Windows is informed by the USB device itself as to the device's identity/functionality.  USB requires that the device have an embedded processor (aka "controller") to process the USB protocol.